# Outputting the numerical value in t.test mean estimates WITHOUT broom

Tags: r

I have data from a t test

```
data("mtcars")
a1=t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars)
```

I want the mean estimates of each group in `am` and no characters but when I do this

```
a1$estimate[1]
a1$estimate[2]
```

I get the characters stating what the values come from mean and the numerical values like this

```
mean in group 0 
       17.14737
```

How do I get only the numerical value using just base R?

I know that `tidy()` from the `broom` package can do this for me easily, but I want to know the base R way to do this for my own edification.

Comment: `a1$estimate` is just a named *numeric* vector. So you can do `as.numeric(a1$estimate[1])` or `unname(a1$estimate[1])`

Comment: You are getting the numerical value, it's just that it has a name which is also displayed. Try `a1$estimate[1] * 2` for example. You can use @MauritsEvers suggestion to display only the value.

Comment: more generally, use `str(a1$estimate)` to explore the underlying structure  of the object ("Named num [1:2]", i.e. a named numeric vector of length 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract the value only, use `[[` instead of `[`:

```
a1$estimate[[1]]
# [1] 17.14737
a1$estimate[[2]]
# [1] 24.39231
```

From the help page of [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html):

> The usual form of indexing is `[`. `[[` can be used to select a single element *dropping* names, whereas `[` keeps them, e.g., in `c(abc = 123)[1]`.

Comment: why do the double brackets return the non-named numerical value vs the single brackets?